# FBX model from Blender doesn't show it's surface in Unity3D

Tags: unity

I've create a model from Blender and exported it as .FBX file. However when I import this into Unity, the surface is missing.how can i fix?

Screenshot attached:

in Blender it look like this:
[image]

in Unity it look like this which only shows it inside:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D objects are made up of a collection of vertices (points in space) that are used to create what we call 'faces' or 'polygons'. Usually, these faces only have 1 visible side. We do this because in normal circumstances we dont want to render the inside of the object (think about a rock, we want to see the outside of the rock, but not the inside). Which side of each face is visible is decided with what we call [normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html). If you click on the link you can see the blue lines reprisenting the direction of the faces. In your case, the blue lines will be pointing towards the inside of the sphere.

This problem is most easily fixed in Blender. You need to invert the direction of the [normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html).

In edit mode select ALL the faces of your mesh ‣ Tool Shelf ‣ Shading/UVs ‣ Shading ‣ Normals: Flip Direction